# bash script to check for folders containing two specific files recursively and print their path

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check recursively for two specific files say "hem" and "haw" and print the folders containing both the files.

Comment: How about `find . -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "{}" && [ -f hem ] && [ -f haw ] && echo {}' \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
shopt -s globstar

for hempath in ./**/hem ; do
    dir=${hempath%/*}
    [[ -e $dir/haw ]] && printf '%s\n' "$dir"
done
```

- See [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for information about `globstar` and the `**` pattern.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${hempath%/*}`.
- The code uses `./**/hem` instead of `**/hem` to ensure that all the matched paths start with `./` so it works even if the files are in the current directory (`.`).
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) to understand why `printf` is used instead of `echo` to print the directory path.
- Note that support for `globstar` was introduced in Bash 4.0, and it was dangerous in versions prior to 4.3 because it used to follow symlinks, possibly leading to infinite recursion (and failure) or unwanted duplicates.  See [When does globstar descend into symlinked directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410987/264812).

Answer (score 1):

```
find <top_folder> -name hem -o name haw -print
```

or

```
cd  <top_folder>
ls **/hem **/haw
```

Comment: Both of these will output folders containing **either** of the two files, not **both**.  And it also doesn’t restrict the result to files, and instead will return every thing.